# How can I reload UITableView when I scroll to the top with current scroll position? (like chat apps)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, chat

I'm working on a chat screen now(UITableView + input TextField).

I want my `UITableView` reload more chat messages staying current scroll position when I scroll to top(If I load older 20 messages more, I still seeing a 21st message.) **KakaoTalk** and **Line** Apps is doing this. In that apps, I can scroll up infinitely because the scroll position is staying.(I mean I'm still seeing the same chat message)

I'm checking the row index in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, so I fetch more chat messages when the index is 0. I finished the logic fetching more messages from DB, but I didn't finish polishing UI.

This is the code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 && !isTableViewLoading {
        if photo.chatMessages.count != chatMessages.count {
            var loadingChatItems: Array<ChatMessage>

            let start = photo.chatMessages.count - chatMessages.count - Metric.ChatMessageFetchAmount
            if start > 0 {
                loadingChatItems = Database.loadChatMessages(photoId, startIndex: start, amount: Metric.ChatMessageFetchAmount)
            } else {
                loadingChatItems = Database.loadChatMessages(photoId, startIndex: 0, amount: Metric.ChatMessageFetchAmount + start)
            }

            chatMessages = loadingChatItems + chatMessages

            isTableViewLoading = true

            var indexPaths = Array<NSIndexPath>()
            for row in 0..<loadingChatItems.count {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
                indexPaths.append(indexPath)
            }

            tableView.scrollEnabled = false
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
        }
    } else {
        isTableViewLoading = false
        tableView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can reload the tableView and keep the same current scroll position, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Nah, What I exactly want to do is that visible cell is staying. If I insert rows to index 0, scroll position is following to that cells now. If visible cell is staying when cells is inserted, I can scroll to the top more to load old chat message again.(like several chat apps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 3**

This post is a bit old, but here a solution:

1) Detect when you are scrolling near to the top in scrollViewDidScroll,

2) Load the new messages

3) Save the contentSize, reload the tableView

4) Set the contentOffset.y of the tableView to (newContentSizeHeight - oldContentSizeHeight) which is exactly the current point

and here the code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == tableView { 
        if tableView.contentOffset.y < 50 {
            loadMessages()
            let oldContentSizeHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
            tableView.reloadData()
            let newContentSizeHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
            tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:tableView.contentOffset.x,y:newContentSizeHeight - oldContentSizeHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks like a good solution, as I'm in the middle of trying to build my first chat app UI and I've not quite gotten to this point.  I do have one question - where would I call your function?  Thanks @Andrea.Ferrando

Comment: @ReneeOlson you don't have to call the function. 
scrollViewDidScroll is a delegate method, so you just need to set your viewController as the delegate of the tableView and then the function will be triggered as soon as you scroll the tableView.

Comment: This is not working when i use tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Then add the function:

```
func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    //your code here

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

}
```

This will allow the user to scroll up to refresh the UITableView.

Comment: I don't get it what you said. Maybe that's not what I want.

Comment: @WooseongKim https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/17/basics-of-pull-to-refresh-for-swift-developers/ Try looking at this tutorial to see if it is what you want. Also I just realized that I left a step out in my original post so if you do do this, follow the tutorial rather than what I said.

Comment: Thank you for your link. I tried the sample proj, but that's not what I want. I want `contentOffset` is changing when I reach the first cell after loading old chat messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented another solution, it uses the scroll listener from the delegate, and the response of the asynchronous service.

So, it scrolls without animation to the position where the loading of more messages started, because messages are being appended to my array (It causes the transition to be barely affected).

I decided to do it in this way because the first solution has a problem, and it is that when you let your row height to be set automatically, then the new content height will not be accurate.

Here's my code.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView  {
    if (!topReached && scrollView == self.table) {
        if (!isLoadingTop && self.table.contentOffset.y < 40) {
            isLoadingTop = YES;
            [self loadChat];
        }
    }
}

// method used by the response of the async service
- (void)fillMessages: (NSArray*) messageArray {
    if ([messageArray count] == 0) {
        topReached = YES;
    } else {

        if ([messageArray count] < limit) {
            topReached = YES;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<messageArray.count; i++) {
            NSDictionary* chat = [messageArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [messages insertObject:[[MessageModel alloc] initWithDictionary:chat] atIndex:i];
        }

        [table reloadData];
        if (!isLoadingTop)
            [self scrollToBottom];
        else {
            isLoadingTop = NO;
            [self.table
                scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[messageArray count] inSection:0]
                atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:false];
        }

        offset += limit;
    }
}
```

As an adicional information, I like to block the access of my async services consumptions in a view controller, so one service can be called just once in the same view.